# join query returning odd results

Tags: php, mysql

I use this query to display a list of songs and show what songs have been clicked as a favorite by a user.

```
$query = mysql_query(
  sprintf("
    SELECT 
      s.*,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date`,
      f.userid as favoritehash
    FROM
      songs s
    LEFT JOIN
      favorites f
    ON 
      f.favorite = s.id
      AND f.userid = %s",
  $userhash)
);
```

The `songs` table is setup as: `id artist title duration` etc. etc.

The `favorites` table is setup as: `id favorite userid`

The `userid` is a hashed value stored in a cookie to reference a unique user.

The query works fine but for some reason if I mark a song as a favorite in one browser. And then mark the same song as favorite in another browser to simulate multiple users the song will be displayed twice... once for each time it is marked favorite but the favorite indicator a <3 will still display correctly.

Any ideas?

Well got it to work via removign the sprintf() but curious to know why this is if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sprintf and %s (string), but you are not enclosing the resulting string value in quotes. If the user ID is a string, then you need to enclose it in quotes, otherwise use %d instead of %s. Since it works fine when you remove sprintf, that would seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue I think if you change the And F.userid = %s to Where f.userid = %s it should fix it?.

Comment: i actually removed the whole sprintf part and it seems to work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

i think your `ON`-clause is wrong.

try this instead:

```
ON f.favorite = s.id
WHERE f.userid = %s
```

Comment: I need it to be AND because I gota make sure the favorite item matches the current song in the song row AND the active user?

Comment: well, that's what this does as far as i am concerned

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the previous suggestions would actually defeat the `LEFT JOIN`, causing it to act as an `INNER JOIN`; `f.userid` would sometimes be `NULL`, and `NULL` always compares as `false`.

I would start by looking at the contents of the `favorites` table. If I understand your schema, you might want to establish a unique key on `favorites` over `favorite` and `userid` to make sure that a given user can only favorite each song once. That is, you may be getting duplicate rows, and hence duplicate results.

Comment: Well its not duplicate rows because I kept an eye on the db as I toyed with it. Once I removed the sprintf() it worked perfectly. And both ID's on both tables are the primary unique key.

Comment: That's very strange. I assume you replaced it with a string concatenation? Was the output of the string operation visibly different after the change?

Also, I did gather that your `id` columns were your primary keys, but you also have a natural key in your favorites table, and you may want to represent it with a new unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a 'left join' I am assuming that you want a list of all the songs and that you want the users favorites to be easily distinguishable. i.e. something like this:

```
song1 details | date | null
song2 details | date | userhash  (favorite)
song3 details | date | null
```

Try the following:

```
SELECT s.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date`, f.userid as favoritehash
FROM
  songs s
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT userid, favorite FROM favorites WHERE userid = %s) f
ON 
  f.favorite = s.id
```